# how to apply date format to anchor tag on View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, date-format

I am using below code to create anchor tag

```
@if (Model.History != null && Model.History.Count > 0)
 {
    foreach (var item in Model.History)
    {
      <a href="@Url.Action("Process", new {item.Id})" class="list-group-item">@item.Id - @item.Name - @item.CreatedOn</a>
    }
 }
 else
 {
   <a href="#" class="list-group-item">No Previous History Found</a>
 }
```

I want to apply date format as June 27, 2017 9:46 PM to @item.CreatedOn

I would like to use moment.js as well for showing local time.

Someone please help me.

Comment: `@item.CreatedOn.ToString(your format)` or add a `DisplayFormat` to your property and use `DisplayFor(m => m.CreatedOn)`

Comment: @Rocky did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The format you're looking for is: **MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm tt**

In your example, just write:

```
@item.CreatedOn.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm tt")
```

The result for today will be: **June 22, 2017 02:40 PM**

Comment: it will work but I would like to use moment.js for date time format, with that I can modify the day in local time because in database I am saving date as UTC

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ToString("u", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` 
to format your date with moment.js like following. "u" corresponds one of format specifier types. İf you are creating a moment from a string, you should check if the string matches known ISO 8601 formats.

.Net Format Specifier Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#Sortable

.Moment Format Reference: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

```
foreach (var item in Model.History)
{
    @*displays like 2008-04-10 13:30:00Z*@
   <a data-utc="@item.startDate.ToString("s", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)" 
        href="@Url.Action("Process", new {item.Id})" 
         class="list-group-item">@item.Id - @item.Name - @item.CreatedOn</a>
}
```

**jquery with moment.js**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('[data-utc]').each(function () {
            var d = moment($(this).attr('data-utc'));
            $(this).html(d.format());
        });
    });
</script>
```